# K3b CD/DVD burning software

Tags: permissions

How can I fix the permissions problem with K3b?

Comment: What problems do you encounter? What error messages do you get? Please [edit] your question to provide that information.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and Google brought me here. Why was this closed? It's pretty clear what's being asked. If anything, simply more details would be needed for this question.

Answer (score 1):

What "permissions problem"?  I'll have to guess.

Is your userid a member of the `cdrom` group?

These commands helped me:

```
walt@bat:~(16)$ ls -l /dev/cdrom
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Sep 11 01:30 /dev/cdrom -> sr0
# /dev/cdrom is /dev/sr0 on my system               ^^^

walt@bat:~(0)$ ls -l /dev/sr0
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Sep 11 01:30 /dev/sr0
# /dev/sr0 is a Block device Read-Writeable by user `root` and members of group `cdrom`

walt@bat:~(0)$ id
uid=1000(walt) gid=1000(walt) groups=1000(walt),4(adm),7(lp),20(dialout),27(sudo),101(systemd-journal),106(input),113(lpadmin),142(motion)
# I'm not in the `cdrom` group

walt@bat:~(0)$ sudo adduser $USER cdrom
[sudo] password for walt: 
Adding user `walt' to group `cdrom' ...
Adding user walt to group cdrom
Done.
# And now I AM a member of group `cdrom`, when I logout/login, or...

walt@bat:~(0)$ newgrp cdrom
# (starts a subshell with GID set)

+walt@bat:~(0)$ id
uid=1000(walt) gid=24(cdrom) groups=24(cdrom),4(adm),7(lp),20(dialout),27(sudo),101(systemd-journal),106(input),113(lpadmin),142(motion),1000(walt)
# I AM a member of the `cdrom` group

+walt@bat:~(0)$ exit
exit
# And now I'm not
walt@bat:~(0)$ id
uid=1000(walt) gid=1000(walt) groups=1000(walt),4(adm),7(lp),20(dialout),27(sudo),101(systemd-journal),106(input),113(lpadmin),142(motion)
```

Comment: When I try to burn a disk it says I don't have permission to do that

Comment: Yes I am a member of the cdrom group

Comment: This does not answer the question. Ubuntu typically puts users in the group `cdrom` automatically. And the OP explicitly stated that this was not the problem either.